# Java methods isbn char conversion and output problems. Can't find out mistake in algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, methods, isbn

I'm trying create a method which returns char type. The condition is this: system takes 9 digits from user input and calculate it. The method converts each char in the nextLine() input and computes the sum then take % 11. If the remainder is 10, method return 'X' and if the remainder is 0 through 9, then the method returns that digit but must be in char type. So far I'm lost at why it will always output '/' and nothing else. Please help me find out the mistake of my algorithms.

```
public static char getCheckSum(String isbn) {
    int sum = 0;
    char charSum;
    for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
        int[] num = new int[isbn.length()]; 
        num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(i) * (i+1);
        sum = sum + num[i];
    }
    int last = (sum % 11);

    if (last == 10){
        charSum = (char) 88;
    } else {
        charSum = (char) (last + 48);
    }
    return charSum;
```

//this is the next part where it inserts hyphens just as a reference

```
public static String formatISBNWithHyphens(String isbn) {
    // original isbn:       123456789
    // possible new isbn:   1-234-56789-X
    char isbn10 = getCheckSum(isbn);
    String isbn10Str = isbn + Character.toString(isbn10);

//  char[] c = new char[isbn10Str.length()];    *leaving this here for future learning.
    String[] cStr = new String[isbn10Str.length()];
    String isbnStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < isbn10Str.length(); i++){
        cStr[i] = Character.toString(isbn10Str.charAt(i));
//      c[i] = isbn10Str.charAt(i);             *leaving this here for future learning.
        if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 8 ) {
            cStr[i] += '-';
         }

         isbnStr += cStr[i];
    }
    return isbnStr;
}
```

// The final outcome is always like this  321654987/  and 3-216-54987-/
it is supposed to be either numbers from 0 to 9 or X if remainder is 10.

Please help. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The last digit(where '/' is now) is supposed to be either numbers from 0 to 9 or a 'X'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
    int[] num = new int[isbn.length()]; 
    num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(i) * (i+1);
    sum = sum + num[i];
}
```

The `for` cycle returning a result has no relationship with the `isbn's` content, the result just depends on the `isbn` string length!

so you can change the code to the following one below

```
for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
        int[] num = new int[isbn.length()]; 
        num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(i));
        sum = sum + num[i];
}
```

the code above returns a result depending on the `isbn's` content

Comment: wow I spent a long time and couldn't find that mistake. But now it seems it won't yield 'X' if the remainder is 10...

Comment: Why the complicated creation of arrays - why don't you just replace the 3 lines inside the for-loop with `sum += Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(i));` ?

Comment: wow I spent a long time and couldn't find that mistake. And Thanks Erwin that is really true. I am a beginner who's learning on my own. I'm pretty bad at coding and coming up with algorithms. But now it seems it won't yield 'X' if the remainder is 10...  Can you please help. It doesn't matter if I change 'charSum = 'X' ' or 'charSum= (char) 88'  it wont give me 'X' when remainder is 10. :/